# Board is not being reset, tic tac toe game

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a tic tac toe game and I am very new to python so I was wondering why my board was not getting reset despite my functions explicitly resetting the board.

I tried getting rid of the function and just implementing a reset where each value was replaced with an underscore like the original Board list but I want to make this more efficient.

CODE

```
import random
score=0
AIscore=0
PlayerSym="X"
AIsymbol="O"
Win=False
ListTF=[True,False]
Board=[["_","_","_"], 
       ["_","_","_"],
       ["_","_","_"]]

def resetGame():
    Board=[["_","_","_"], 
       ["_","_","_"],
       ["_","_","_"]]
    print("resetting board ///////////////////////////////////////////")


def initiateGame(Win,AIsymbol):
    print("Welcome to tic tac toe")
    print("If you score 3 points you win")
    print("pick a row and column to place your symbol:")
    
    
def Symbols():
    TF=random.choice(ListTF)
    if Win==False:
        PlayerSym="X"
        print("player, you are 'X' so you go first")
        AIsymbol="O"
    else:
        if TF==True:
            PlayerSym="X"
            AIsymbol="O"
            print("player, you are 'X' so you go first")
        if TF==False:
            PlayerSym="O"
            AIsymbol="X"
            print("player, you are 'O' so you go second")    


def GameWinner(score,Board,AIscore):
    for row in range(0,3): #checks all columns for a win
        if(Board[row][0]==Board[row][1] == Board[row][2] == PlayerSym):
            Win=True
            print("congrats, you have earned a point")
            print("the score is:")
            score=score+1
            print("Player:",score)
            print("AI:",AIscore)
            resetGame()
        elif(Board[row][0]==Board[row][1] == Board[row][2] == AIsymbol):
            Win=False
            print("The AI has earned a point")
            print("the score is:")
            print("Player:",score)
            AIscore=AIscore+1
            print("AI:",AIscore)
            resetGame()  
    if(Board[0][0]==Board[1][1] == Board[2][2] == PlayerSym):
        Win=True
        print("congrats, you have earned a point")
        print("the score is:")
        score=score+1
        print("Player:",score)
        print("AI:",AIscore)
        resetGame()
    elif(Board[0][0]==Board[1][1] == Board[2][2] == AIsymbol):
        Win=False
        print("The AI has earned a point")
        print("the score is:")
        print("Player:",score)
        AIscore=AIscore+1
        print("AI:",AIscore)
        resetGame()
    if(Board[0][2]==Board[2][0] == Board[1][1] == PlayerSym):
        Win=True
        print("congrats, you have earned a point")
        print("the score is:")
        score=score+1
        print("Player:",score)
        print("AI:",AIscore)
        resetGame()
    elif(Board[0][2]==Board[2][0] == Board[1][1] == AIsymbol):
        Win=False
        print("The AI has earned a point")
        print("the score is:")
        print("Player:",score)
        AIscore=AIscore+1
        print("AI:",AIscore)
        resetGame() 
        
def Space(Board,PlayerSym,AIsymbol):
    print(Board[0])
    print(Board[1])
    print(Board[2])
    row=int(input("pick a row from (0-2):"))
    column=int(input("pick a column from (0-2)"))
    while (row>2 or row<0) or (column>2 or column<0):
        print("you entered a value that is not within the parameters, pick again")
        row=int(input("pick a row from (0-2):"))
        column=int(input("pick a column from (0-2)"))
    while (Board[row][column]==PlayerSym or Board[row][column]==AIsymbol):
        print("your row and column already has an 'X' or 'O', pick again") 
        row=int(input("pick a row from (0-2):"))
        column=int(input("pick a column from (0-2)"))
    Board[row][column]=PlayerSym
    

initiateGame(Win,AIsymbol)

def main():
        Symbols()
        GameWinner(score,Board,AIscore)
        Space(Board,PlayerSym,AIsymbol)
        

while True:
    main()
```

Comment: What is your definition of more efficient?  Shorter c ode, quicker execution?  What specifically is wrong with your current implementation.  Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @quamrana stated, your `resetGame()` function is spawning a new `Board = [[ ... ]]`, but that's all it is doing here. You are not referencing the previously spawned `Board` at all, so this new `Board` that exists within the `resetGame()` scope and does not interact with the global version that you are trying to reset. A simple fix for this would be to return your new board, and assign that value whenever you'd like the board reset. E.g.:

```
def resetGame():
    newBoard =[["_","_","_"], 
               ["_","_","_"],
               ["_","_","_"]]
    return newBoard 

   ...

Board = resetGame()
```

Alternatively, you can target the global variable directly with the `global` keyword, which adds the variable in question to the method scope:

```
def resetGame():
    global Board
    Board= [["_","_","_"], 
            ["_","_","_"],
            ["_","_","_"]]

   ...

resetGame()
```

Here's a good resource on how scope works in python to help you: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Cheers, best of luck!

Comment: Saying "good resource" about w3schools is making me cringe...

Comment: @KellyBundy Honestly yeah I'll give you that haha ... but hey if you're new, it aint too bad !!

Comment: I rather think the opposite, being new makes one more vulnerable to misinformation.

Comment: The second method worked, thank you